# mysql query to concat information from 3 tables - getting incorrect result count

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables in my database.

> - ab_contacts
>
>   - id
>   - first_name
>   - last_name
>   - addressbook_id
>   - etc (more, but these are the relevant ones)
> - ab_addressbooks
>
>   - name
>   - id
> - co_comments
>
>   - id
>   - link_id
>   - comment

I'd like to create a query that will let me select all the contacts and comments related to them in a given addressbook.

To select all the people in a given addressbook, I can use:

`select count(*) from ab_contacts where addressbook_id = '50';`

This returns 8152 people.

However, when I run my query:

```
select
  ab_addressbooks.name,
  ab_contacts.first_name,
  ab_contacts.last_name,
  ab_contacts.email,
  ab_contacts.email2,
  ab_contacts.email3,
  ab_contacts.function,
  ab_contacts.address,
  ab_contacts.address_no,
  ab_contacts.city,
  ab_contacts.state,
  ab_contacts.zip,
  ab_contacts.home_phone,
  ab_contacts.work_phone,
  ab_contacts.cellular,
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ab_contacts.comment, '\r', ', '), '\n', ', '), '\\', '') AS comment,
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(group_concat(co_comments.comments separator ', '), '\r', ', '), '\n', ', '), '\\', '') AS comment2
from ab_contacts
LEFT JOIN ab_addressbooks ON (ab_contacts.addressbook_id = ab_addressbooks.id)
LEFT JOIN co_comments ON (ab_contacts.id = co_comments.link_id)
WHERE ab_contacts.addressbook_id = '344';`
```

the format works, but I only get 1045 results.  I'm sure there is something I am missing, but I cannot figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try replace your `JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`, to get people without comments, and maybe also add a `GROUP BY ab_contacts.id` if that results in to many rows

Comment: That is weird... adding the GROUP BY got me the right number.  This worked fantastically.  Thanks!

Comment: your first query gave you one row per comment, replacing `(INNER) JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN` extended it to at least one row per contact, contacts with more than one comment got one row per comment, adding a group by gives you max one row per contact

Comment: Does this mean that if a contact has more than one comment, not all the comments will show up?

Comment: yes, you can either use `GROUP_CONCAT(comment)` to get all comment at the same row, or skip the `GROUP BY` to get multiple rows of the same contact

Comment: I have group_concat in my query above, will that keep all the comments together as shown?

Comment: 1. please don't change the question, add more information to the bottom of the question insted, 2. if you use group_concat without group by you going to end up with just one row

Answer (score 1):

If you [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html) other tables to your table adressbook, MySQL interprets this as an [`INNER JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html). This means only rows with corresponding data in the other tables will be returned, in case they don't have corresponding data they won't be in your result.

If this is not what you want, you have to use a different [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html) type (most likely a [`LEFT JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html)), keep in mind your result will have `NULL` values in the fields where there is no relating data in the other tables.

Comment: That was 90% of my issue. From what I can tell (still trying to figure out why), the other part was adding a GROUP BY as in the answer above.  Thanks!